# Swift compare two MetaTypes?

Tags: swift

I need to test to see if a Type I'm passing to a function is of a certain class or not

```
func doSomething<T> (type: T.Type) -> T {

   // Check to see if type is the same as Raw type?

   if type == Raw.self { } // Doesn't work, Compile error

   if type is? Raw.self { } // Doesn't work, Compile error
}

@objc class Raw {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function overloading would be my first choice, but to answer the question; either use `NSStringFromClass`, or the following:

```
@objc class Raw {

}

func doSomething<T: AnyObject> (type: T.Type) -> T {

    type as AnyClass === Raw.self as AnyClass { }

    // return something
}
```

This solution seems to work with pure Swift classes too.

Comment: There has to be a better way, to simply compare classes similar to Objective C